# TestComplete On-Demand Video Training

Tags: automated-testing, learning, training

SmartBear, the vendor for TestComplete automation tool, have over a 90 on-demand training videos available covering various subjects. However, it costs $349 for a years access.

Has anyone watched these videos? 
Is it worth spending the money? 
Did you learn how to really use TestComplete to test your application(s)?

http://www2.smartbear.com/TestComplete-On-Demand-Training-Video-LP

Comment: I'm not certain this question can be objectively answered. Something being "worth the money" is almost guaranteed to be opinion based. The only way I could see it being non-opinion based would be something like "they videos seem almost identical to example.com's selection for only $49 a year" which is a pretty narrow scope of allowable answers.